# Getting url from Database and putting as an image for UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

All,

I need to assign a picture to a UITableView. Each row has a different picture. The data for each row comes from a database and a row on that database has an ID, the ID in another database is linked and that has a URL in that table for the image.

So within cellforRowAtIndexPath we have : 
NSDictionary *postValues = @{@"myParam": apt[@"barID"]};

```
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://outnight-mobile.azure-mobile.net/" applicationKey:@"okYeRGfBagYrsbkaqWIRObeDtktjkF10"];
[self.client invokeAPI:@"photos"
                  body:postValues
            HTTPMethod:@"POST"
            parameters:nil
               headers:nil
            completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error %@", error );
                } else
                {
                    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [result objectForKey:@"rows"]];
                    NSString *stringWithoutbracketsend = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
                    NSString *stringWithoutbracketsfront = [stringWithoutbracketsend stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
                    NSString *completion = [stringWithoutbracketsfront stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                    NSString *newStr = [completion substringFromIndex:1];
                    NSString *finalstring = [newStr substringToIndex:newStr.length-(newStr.length>0)];
                    NSLog(@"%@", finalstring);
                    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:finalstring] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];

                }
            }];
```

That brings in the url from the table, which was JSON and I removed all the tags to get a string thats just http://blag.com/bah.jpg' This is the easy bit. 
I am using SBWebImage for putting the image in the uitableview async which is fine too. What is the  best way of putting the images on each row from the url. is it best with a SWITCH statement ? Is it best with an array of URL's and then displaying them. Is it best to move the database connectivity from cellforIndexRowPath? Can anyone advice please ?

Comment: We only want the top three in the UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a custom view cell for the uitableview. And then add subviews like images, labels to the custom cell.Get the data from the database to an array of images, arrays of ID'sIn the tableview delegate methods at cellforrowatindex use the code.

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    if(tableView == myTableView){
        FirstViewCustomCell *cell = (FirstViewCustomCell *)[myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FirstViewCustomCell" owner:self
                                        options:nil];
            cell = customCell;
            customCell = nil;
        }
        [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
      //Get the data from the database.
      cell.customimage.image = [imagesarr objectatIndex:indexpath.row];
      cell.textlabel.text = [arrayofID objectatIndex:indexpath.row];
}

Comment: thanks for the information mate but you have lost me!!

Answer (score 0):

Parse the data seperately..in an method and then

Store images in an array..As you want top three images..

If you are saving the urls of image in an object and then array..Use below code

```
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    ImagesObject *Obj=[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i];

            [cell.userProfilePicImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Obj.imageURLString]
                                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]
                                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
             {
                 if (!error && image)
                 {

                 }
             }];
        }

        (or) if you are not saving in an object then use below code.

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {

        NSString *imageURLString=[imagesArray objectAtIndex:i];

                [cell.userProfilePicImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString]
                                         placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]
                                                completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType)
                 {
                     if (!error && image)
                     {

                     }
                 }];
}
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: yes I get it, so create an array of all the image URL's in a method somewhere. Call the method to fill the array. then put the above code in viewforcellrowsatindex.

Comment: @user3229170 YES...If you want to store only imageurl in an array then use second for loop code else if you want to store anything with imageurl better to use object and store all in an object and then to array. Use first for loop..

Comment: I am trying to make a method from my SQL block and the return statement is now allowed, any ideas ?